Seeking Expert Assistance for Compiling and Running IDA-Generated C Code
Although I'm not new to programming, I'm currently unfamiliar with C language specifics. I have a code snippet generated using IDA and I'm encountering difficulties in compiling and running it.
I'm seeking the expertise of experienced developers who are proficient in C programming to assist me in compiling and executing this code successfully. Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your support!
int fastcall sub_2A84(int a1, int a2, int a3)
{
  int v6; // r0
  int v7; // r12
  int v8; // r1
  char v9; // r2
  unsigned int v10; // t1
  unsigned int v11; // r3
  FILE *v12; // r0
  FILE *v13; // r7
  FILE *v14; // r0
  FILE *v15; // r5
  _DWORD v17[17]; // [sp+4h] [bp-44h] BYREF

  v17[0] = -549955056;
  v17[1] = 942652330;
  v17[2] = 1601953408;
  v17[3] = -1922941098;
  v6 = -904764173;
  v17[4] = -904764173;
  v17[5] = -31309516;
  v17[6] = -655969042;
  v17[7] = 943924076;
  if ( a2 )
  {
    v7 = a1 - 1;
    v8 = 0;
    do
    {
      v10 = *(unsigned __int8 *)++v7;
      v9 = v10;
      ++v8;
      v11 = v10 + (v10 >> 5);
      if ( v8 <= 31 )
        v6 = 0;
      if ( v8 > 31 )
        v6 = 1;
      if ( a2 <= v8 )
        v6 |= 1u;
      *((_BYTE *)v17 + (v11 & 0x1F)) ^= v9;
    }
    while ( !v6 );
  }
  v12 = (FILE *)fopen64("/tmp/test-123456-test.txt", "w");
  v13 = v12;
  if ( !v12 )
    return -1;
  fwrite(v17, 0x20u, 1u, v12);
  fclose(v13);
  v14 = popen("md5sum /tmp/test-123456-test.txt | awk '{print $1}'", "r");
  v15 = v14;
  if ( !v14 )
    return -1;
  fscanf(v14, "%32[^\n]", a3);
  pclose(v15);
  system("rm -rf /tmp/test-123456-test.txt");
  return 0;
}

I attempted to use AI platforms to understand and run the IDA-generated C code, but unfortunately, I wasn't successful. As I'm not familiar with C programming, I couldn't effectively troubleshoot the issues or interpret the code correctly. That's why I'm reaching out to experienced developers for guidance and assistance.

Well, first thing you need is the main function...

Read some "getting started with C" tutorial and look at the "Hello World" example program they have you create/  Or in an IDE like Visual Studio stat a new console app using C as the language.  Those both give you a skeleton app to add this code into.  The paths look like Linux so probably a Linux IDE.

Successfully run, end
